# How to import SQL database from file to Azure

Tags: sql, azure, import, mysql-workbench

How to load my SQL database created in MySQL Workbench on Azure cloud?

I created a database which consists of some tables - for now, there is now data in them, it's just a small script created by MySQL Workbench. I also created a database on Azure cloud, created login & password and when I want to use 'automated export' option (I have Storage account, I enter valid login with password) I have error:

'Could not find any bacpac files in the specified storage account.'

I tried google this phrase but I completely do not understand the idea behind these bacpac files and I do not know what to do with it. Can anyone describe me step-by-step how to put my database on Azure cloud?

I want to connect to this DB on Azure in the future because I would like to do a webapplication and android app which will use a remote DB available online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL Database is a custom SQL Server, so if you want to use MySQL you should create a Clear DB (which is a Microsoft partner that offers MySQL on azure). Other option, you can create a Virtual Machine and install by yourself a MySQL.

After that, you can import your tables / records.